# mediaplayer not playing file within alert dialog

Tags: android, media-player, audio-streaming

I've an app where an AlertDialog pops up in a certain condition. I'd like to attach a sound to it as it shows. My Activity is called NfcScannerActivity.

I'm trying to use the MediaPlayer to play the sound but it does't play. The file is meep2.mp3 and is in thr Raw folder. Any ideas why it does't play?

thanks.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    NfcscannerActivity.this);

                                // set title
                                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Sign In Alert ");

                                // set dialog message
                                alertDialogBuilder
                                    .setMessage("You have just signed out from this tag. ( " + tagUserName + " )" +
                                            " Click OK to sign back in at this client or click CANCEL to decline the sign in")
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                            //do something

                                        }
                                      })
                                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                                            // the dialog box and do nothing

                                            dialog.cancel();

                                            Log.e(TAG, "Cancelled the transaction as already signed out within last 2 mins on same tag");
                                        }
                                    });

                                    // create alert dialog
                                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                                    try{
                                    // show it
                                    alertDialog.show();


                                    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(NfcscannerActivity.this, R.raw.meep2); 
                                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                    //mediaPlayer.release();
                                    //mediaPlayer = null; 

                                    }catch(Exception e){

                                        //ignore
                                    }
```

[edit]

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(NfcscannerActivity.this, R.raw.alert); 
                                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                                            mp.release();

                                        }
                                    });
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, but you don't have to call `mediaPlayer.prepare();` after creating it with `MediaPlayer.create(..)`. [Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

Comment: @Doc Thanks it works now. Do i have to call release()? or is there any tidying up to be done after playing (releasing resources)

Comment: You should implement a [onCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) and then register it with [setOnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29). In that listener, you should call `mediaPlayer.release()`

Comment: @MalaKa thanks i've edited the post. going to test it now.

Comment: i'll accept an answer if one is made. Thanks again

Comment: Your welcome, answer created ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) of `MediaPlayer.create(..)`, you don't need to call `mediaPlayer.prepare()` anymore.
But you may implement the [MediaPlayer.onCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html), that can be registered to the `MediaPlayer` with [setOnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29). In this callback, you should release the resources of the `MediaPlayer` with `mediaPlayer.release()`.